# Error in your SQL syntax for INNER JOINS

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to run this mysql query through rstudio, but I keep getting an error. Any idea why?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT host.key AS 'uid',
 daily_summary.date AS 'date' 
 FROM host INNER JOIN daily_summary 
 USING(weekly_id);
```

This is the error I get.

```
42000 1064 [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.40-
0ubuntu0.14.04.1]You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM host INNER 
JOIN daily_summary USING(weekly_id)' at line 1
```

Comment: Start by removing the surplus comma after `host.key` :`SELECT host.key AS 'uid',` maybe that helps? Also, use double-quotes or backticks for the uid and date aliases.

Comment: Got to be the comma. At least, that's part of it.

Comment: @CargoMeister yeah, and the was another one just before `from` that I dodn't even notice. In any case the OP should have picked up on this easily.

Comment: Are you still getting the error after fixing the typos?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query as it would better be written:

```
SELECT host.key AS uid, daily_summary.date
FROM host INNER JOIN
     daily_summary 
     USING(weekly_id);
```

In addition to removing the spurious commas, this also removes the unneeded quotes around the column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Otherwise, they are likely to cause confusion in queries.  If you need to escape aliases in MySQL, then use backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Check version simplified without typos:

```
SELECT host.key, daily_summary.date
FROM host INNER JOIN daily_summary 
USING(weekly_id);
```

I also prefer to use word ON instead of USING:

```
SELECT host.key, daily_summary.date
FROM host INNER JOIN daily_summary 
ON host.weekly_id = daily_summary.weekly_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL syntax error message shows you part of your statement starting with the first character it can't understand.  In your case the first characters it can't understand are `FROM`.  It's looking for another column name after the comma.